# class attribute lookup rule?

Tags: python, python-internals

```
>>> class D:
...     __class__ = 1
...     __name__ = 2
...
>>> D.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> D().__class__
1
>>> D.__name__
'D'
>>> D().__name__
2
```

**Why does `D.__class__` return the name of the class, while `D().__class__` returns the defined attribute in class D?**

**And from where do builtin attributes such as `__class__` and `__name__` come from?**

I suspected `__name__` or `__class__` to be simple descriptors that live either in `object` class or somewhere, but this can't be seen.

In my understanding, the attribute lookup rule as follows in Python, omitting the conditions for descriptors etc..:

`Instance --> Class --> Class.__bases__ and the bases of the other classes as well`

Given the fact that a class is an instance of a metaclass, `type` in this case, why `D.__class__` doesn't look for `__class__` in `D.__dict__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The names `__class__` and `__name__` are special. Both are *data descriptors*. `__name__` is defined on the `type` object, `__class__` is defined on `object` (a base-class of all new-style classes):

```
>>> type.__dict__['__name__']
<attribute '__name__' of 'type' objects>
>>> type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of getset_descriptor object at 0x1059ea870>
>>> type.__dict__['__name__'].__set__
<method-wrapper '__set__' of getset_descriptor object at 0x1059ea870>
>>> object.__dict__['__class__']
<attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>
>>> object.__dict__['__class__'].__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of getset_descriptor object at 0x1059ea2d0>
>>> object.__dict__['__class__'].__set__
<method-wrapper '__set__' of getset_descriptor object at 0x1059ea2d0>
```

Because they are data descriptors, the [`type.__getattribute__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) (used for attribute access on a class) will ignore any attributes set in the class `__dict__` and only use the descriptors themselves:

```
>>> type.__getattribute__(Foo, '__class__')
<class 'type'>
>>> type.__getattribute__(Foo, '__name__')
'Foo'
```

Fun fact: `type` derives from `object` (*everything* in Python is an object) which is why `__class__` is found on `type` when checking for data descriptors:

```
>>> type.__mro__
(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)
```

(`type.__getattribute__(D, ...)` is used directly as an unbound method, not `D.__getattribute__()`, because [all special method access goes to the type](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup)).

See the [*Descriptor Howto*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) an what constitutes a data descriptor and why that matters:

> If an object defines both `__get__()` and `__set__()`, it is considered a data descriptor. Descriptors that only define `__get__()` are called non-data descriptors (they are typically used for methods but other uses are possible).
>
> Data and non-data descriptors differ in how overrides are calculated with respect to entries in an instance’s dictionary. If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data descriptor, the data descriptor takes precedence. If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence.

For data descriptors on `type`, a class is just another instance.

So when looking up the `__class__` or `__name__` attributes, it doesn't matter what is defined in the `D.__dict__` namespace, because for either a data descriptor is found in the namespace formed by `type` and it's MRO.

These descriptors are defined in the [`typeobject.c` C code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/typeobject.c):

```c
static PyGetSetDef type_getsets[] = {
    {"__name__", (getter)type_name, (setter)type_set_name, NULL},
    /* ... several more ... */
}

/* ... */

PyTypeObject PyType_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "type",                                     /* tp_name */
    /* ... many type definition entries ... */
    type_getsets,                               /* tp_getset */
    /* ... many type definition entries ... */
}

/* ... */

static PyGetSetDef object_getsets[] = {
    {"__class__", object_get_class, object_set_class,
     PyDoc_STR("the object's class")},
    {0}
};

PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    /* ... many type definition entries ... */
    object_getsets,                             /* tp_getset */
    /* ... many type definition entries ... */
}
```

On instances, `object.__getattribute__` is used, and it'll find the `__name__` and `__class__` entries in the `D.__dict__` mapping before it'll find the data descriptors on `object` or `type`.

If you omit either, however, then looking up the names on `D()` will only `__class__` as a data descriptor in the MRO of `D` (so, on `object`). `__name__` is not found as the metatypes are not considered when resolving instance attributes.

As such you can set `__name__` on an instance, but not `__class__`:

```
>>> class E: pass
...
>>> e = E()
>>> e.__class__
<class '__main__.E'>
>>> e.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'E' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> e.__dict__['__class__'] = 'ignored'
>>> e.__class__
<class '__main__.E'>
>>> e.__name__ = 'this just works'
>>> e.__name__
'this just works'
```

Comment: I get most of the parts of your answer and to test that: the rules for attribute lookup differs for classes and instances. I can see `type.__getattribute__` gives data descriptors higher precedence, same as `object.__getattribute__`. But both `type.__getattribute__` and `object.__getattribute__` check the type of an object. If it's an instance of a class, `__dict__` is searched before the data descriptors. Is that right?

Comment: @direprobs: what happens is that you start attribute lookup on an object, and Python always does `type(object).__getattribute__(object, attribute_name)`; for class objects that's `type.__getattribute__`, for instances that's the `object.__getattribute__` (in both cases unless redefined by a subtype / subclass). So the 'type check' takes place *before* `__getattribute__` is even called.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The thing is,  I tried `type.__getattribute__(A, '__class__')` which returns `<class 'type'>`. As such, both  `type.__getattribute__` and `object.__getattribute__` consider data descriptors with higher precedence than `__dict__` for (Classes) and not (Instances). But when I ran `type.__getattribute__(A(), '__class__')` this returns `1`. This suggests to me that there's some sort of type checking (whether the object passed to `__getattribute__` is a class or an instance of a class), if it's a class then Python will look for data descriptors first.

Comment: @direprobs: after that, `type.__getattribute__` and `object.__getattribute__` are slightly different implementations of the same principles: search for an attribute in the current object or its 'type'. For instances, look at `__dict__` and the class (including the full MRO), with data descriptors taking precedence over instance `__dict__` entries. For classes, look at the class with full MRO and the metatype with full MRO, and again data descriptors trump anything found in the class hierarchy.

Comment: _"For instances, look at `__dict__`and the class (including the full MRO), with data descriptors taking precedence over instance `__dict__` entries."_ Then why does `A().__class__` return 1 although in the MRO of class `A` there's `__class__`, a data descriptor in `object`?

Comment: @direprobs: the **first** `__class__` in the MRO of `A` is `A.__dict__['__class__']`. Searching stops there, `object.__dict__['__class__']` is never found.

Comment: But we said the data descriptors have higher precedence than `__dict__` attributes?

Comment: @direprobs: if the name exists both as a data descriptor in the MRO, and as a key in the instance `__dict__`, the data descriptor wins over the instance `__dict__` entry. Finding the data descriptor in the MRO is still just a search for the first hit on the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121998/discussion-between-direprobs-and-martijn-pieters).